Is there a way to freeze the top and bottom row of a table using only inline CSS?
I can freeze a the top row doing this:
<table>
 <thead>
  <tr style='background: grey; position: sticky; top:0;'>
   <th>Col1</th>
   <th>Col2</th>
   <th>Col3</th>
   <th>Col4</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
<table>

However, I am unsure if I could freeze the bottom row. I have totals and aggregate data that I wish would remain visible at the bottom of the table. Is this even possible?

Would this do what you want?  It's a bit unclear exactly what your asking, but I think this should solve it.


<div style="height: 400px; overflow-y: scroll;">
  <table style="width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse;">
    <thead>
      <tr style="background: grey; position: sticky; top: 0;">
        <th>Col1</th>
        <th>Col2</th>
        <th>Col3</th>
        <th>Col4</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Data 1</td>
        <td>Data 2</td>
        <td>Data 3</td>
        <td>Data 4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Data 5</td>
        <td>Data 6</td>
        <td>Data 7</td>
        <td>Data 8</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Data 9</td>
        <td>Data 10</td>
        <td>Data 11</td>
        <td>Data 12</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
      <tr style="background: lightgrey; position: sticky; bottom: 0;">
        <td colspan="4">Total</td>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
  </table>
</div>




Yes! This is what I was looking for! Thank you!
